# Use both LIKE and NOT LIKE in the same query

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, sqldf

I have a `df` like this

```
Category <- c('D_L','D_R','FA1','LBP0W','L-010','L-020','LW_-010','LWA_PT_035','LWA_PT_055','RBP0W','RET_MAG','R-010','R-000','RWA_PT_035','RWA_PT_055','TPH')
ID <- c(111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126)
df <- data.frame(ID,Category)
df

    ID   Category
1  111        D_L
2  112        D_R
3  113        FA1
4  114      LBP0W
5  115      L-010
6  116      L-020
7  117    LW_-010
8  118 LWA_PT_035
9  119 LWA_PT_055
10 120      RBP0W
11 121    RET_MAG
12 122      R-010
13 123      R-000
14 124 RWA_PT_035
15 125 RWA_PT_055
16 126        TPH
```

I am using sqldf to filter my dataset into 2 categories.

```
df_R <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df 
                  WHERE Category NOT LIKE '%_L'
                  AND Category NOT LIKE 'LW_%'
                  AND category NOT LIKE 'L-%'
                  AND category NOT LIKE 'LB%'")

df_L <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df 
              WHERE Category NOT LIKE '%_R'
              AND Category NOT LIKE 'RW_%'
              AND category NOT LIKE 'R-%'
              AND category NOT LIKE 'RB%'")
```

Here I get 2 data frames.
Challenge is that:

1) for df_R - I need to return "RWA_PT_035" & not "RWA_PT_055" category 
2) for df_L - I need to return "LWA_PT_035" & not "LWA_PT_055" category

and hence when I try to do this

```
df_R <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df 
                      WHERE Category NOT LIKE '%_L'
                      AND Category NOT LIKE 'LW_%'
                      AND Category NOT LIKE 'L-%'
                      AND Category NOT LIKE 'LB%'
                      AND Category LIKE 'RWA_PT_035'")
```

it returns only 1 observation and that is "RWA_PT_035" for df_R but my desired output is

```
   ID   Category
1 112        D_R
2 113        FA1
3 120      RBP0W
4 121    RET_MAG
5 122      R-010
6 123      R-000
7 124 RWA_PT_035
8 126        TPH
```

and for df_L

```
    ID   Category
1  111        D_L
2  113        FA1
3  114      LBP0W
4  115      L-010
5  116      L-020
6  117    LW_-010
7  118 LWA_PT_035
8  121    RET_MAG
9 126        TPH
```

I would like to know if I could use "LIKE" and "NOT LIKE" in a query at the same time like the above? or if there is any other way to do this?

I am also open to other methods like data.table or dplyr instead of sqldf.

Comment: Seems like you can wrap it up into one simple `grepl` statement or am I missing something? `df[!grepl("L|_PT_055", df$Category),]`

Comment: This works for df_R but when I do it for df_L, it ignores the "RET_MAG" value in category. Could you please check it?

Comment: I don't understand you filtering rules, why do you want to keep `RET_MAG` in `df_L`?

Comment: because I only want to filter anything that is _ R, RW _, R-, RB. Whereas RET_MAG, TPH, FA1 are constant values that needs to be returned for both df_R & df_L.

Comment: Then maybe `df[!grepl("_R|RWA_|R-|RB|_PT_055", df$Category),]` or sometihng similar

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much David. Much appreciated. It was indeed an easy fix but still I couldn't get it!!

Comment: @Sharath you can self-answer your question or delete it to not leave unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution from David Arenburg

```
df[!grepl("_R|RWA_|R-|RB|_PT_055", df$Category),]
```

Answer (score 1):

To replicate @DavidArenburg solution using `sqldf`:

```
#Using @DavidArenburg solution:
res1 <- df[!grepl("_R|RWA_|R-|RB|_PT_055", df$Category),]

#Using sqldf
library(sqldf)
res2 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df 
               WHERE Category NOT LIKE '%_R' AND
                     Category NOT LIKE 'RWA_%' AND
                     Category NOT LIKE 'R-%' AND
                     Category NOT LIKE 'RB%' AND
                     Category NOT LIKE '%_PT_055'")

# res1 == res2
#      ID Category
# 1  TRUE     TRUE
# 3  TRUE     TRUE
# 4  TRUE     TRUE
# 5  TRUE     TRUE
# 6  TRUE     TRUE
# 7  TRUE     TRUE
# 8  TRUE     TRUE
# 11 TRUE     TRUE
# 16 TRUE     TRUE
```

Comment: This SQL string can also be created dynamically like this: `expr <- sprintf("'%s'", c('%_R', 'RWA_%', 'R-%', 'RB%', '%_PT_055')); notlikes <- paste( paste('CATEGORY NOT LIKE', expr), collapse = " AND "); fn$sqldf("SELECT * FROM df WHERE $notlikes")`